# Include Phone Gap Plugin in Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cordova, plugins

Im new to phonegap features.

My doubt is how to add a new cordova plugin to my ruby on rails code.
Please help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ran into similar issues, and finally wrote a blog entry about my solution.  It discusses how to load up the assets on the Rails website, rolling your own user_agent string (I'm assuming your site will be taking requests from normal browsers, as well as a Cordova app?), etc.

One key piece is using a non-standard cordova.js files.  See Cordova Issue CB-6505 for details.  The Cordova team has plans to solve this issue (fetching minified assets from a remote host), but this hasn't been completed yet.

I ended up splitting the JavaScript assets into chunks, 3 in my case.  One chunk is supplied for all requests and includes jQuery, Bootstrap and some other generic code.  the other 2 chunks, (one for iOS App requests and one for Android App requests) have the Cordova specific files.  I used 3 different Manifest files to accomplish that, and 2 subdirectories under the rails app/assets/javascripts directory.  The subdirs contain the architecture-specific cordova.js and cordova_plugins.js files, plus all the plugin Javascript files.  Depending on the plugins you need, you might be able to put them all in the generic chunk.  In my case, I needed slightly different sets of plugins depending on the architecture.  In any case, you'll need to supply the architecture specific cordova.js files depending on which device is accessing your Rails site.  Whenever I add/change the Cordova Plugins used, they need to get copied into the Rails website codebase too.

I also needed to be able to differentiate an access from my Cordova app, from a web browser running on the same device.  On the Rails side, I added a 'before filter' that sets some @vars that can be used in the app/views/layouts/application.html.erb file to choose which of the JavaScript asset chunks to serve up.  The filter uses the user-agent string to determine which chunks to serve.

For additional details see: http://craigapayne.blogspot.com/2014/07/creating-truly-hybrid-app-and-backing.html

Comment: Is there a GIT repo I can take a look at? Not sure I can make it only based on these comments.